# JDialog with minimize button

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

Is it possible to have a minimize and maximize button for a non-modal(modal=false)  JDialog.I know JFrame is the ideal solution for this but this change has to be made in an existing code and its little difficult to change from JDialog to JFrame.

Comment: But do you know how to have maximize and minimize buttons on modal JDialog?

Answer (score 4):

No, JDialog cannot be decorated with a minimize button (modal or not).

Comment: Indeed...This is insane